# C++ making int array using new operation

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a dynamic array using new operator.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Set{
   public:
      Set() { count = 0; }
      Set(int i) {
         elements = new int;
         elements[0] = i;
         count = 1;
      }
      void add(int new_element) {
         if(find(new_element) != -1) {
            cout << "The set has " << new_element << " already.\n";
            return;
         }
         else {
//          elements[count] = new int;
            elements[count++] = new_element;
            cout << elements[count-1] << endl;
         }
      }
      void remove(int remove_element) {
         int index = find(remove_element);
         if(index == -1) {
            cout << "The set doesn't have " << remove_element << ".\n";
            return;
         }
         else {
            for(int i=index ; i<count ; i++)
               elements[i] = elements[i+1];
            count--;
     }
  }
  void enumerate() {
     for(int i=0 ; i<count ; i++)
        cout << elements[i] << " ";
     cout << endl;
  }
  ~Set() {
  }
   private:
      int* elements;
      int count;
      int find(int temp_element) {
         int i=0;
         for( ; i<count ; i++)
            if(elements[i] == temp_element)
               return i;
         return -1;
      }
};

int main() {
   Set s1(1);
   s1.add(2);
   s1.add(3);
   s1.remove(2);
   s1.add(4);
   s1.add(5);
   s1.enumerate();
   return 0;
```

I already know that using STL makes this problem easier. But, I want to know why this code making the error. And, I don't know why it works without line 18. At last, how can I free the allocated storage? Please, Let me know the answer.

Comment: To free the storage, you simply do `delete[] elements` but that will only work if `elements` points to something created with `new[]`. Inside your constructor, you allocate space for one integer using `new`, so only `delete` will work on `elements`.

Comment: Moreover, in your `add()` method you do `elements[count++] = new_element` without first checking if there is enough space in the array to accommodate another object. If there isn't enough space you need to reallocate the array by some size, copy the elements over, and add the new element.

Comment: `elements = new int;` - That's a pointer to a single element. You use it as if it has more.

Comment: Don't forget also the rule of 5 (or 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared `elements` as an `pointer to int`. That meains that `elements[i]` is a plain `int`. By writing

```
elements[count] = new int;
```

Your attempting to assign an pointer to some newly allocated int to it. It's not working because `elements[count]` is already an `int` and not a pointer.

As for freeing the allocated storage, a `std::vector` simply keeps track how many elements it contains lets use `n`. Then everything from `data[0]` to `data[n-1]` will be your actual information. If it had more storage at the end, it simply leaves it there without deallocating it and with some trash value and doesn't let you access it. You can resize it by making a new array with your new size, copying every element over from the old storage, then calling `delete[]` on the old pointer. Watch out for possible memory leaks though.